# W3 total cache Directory change

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

I have changed the w3 total cache directory in wordpress project, and all the settings are appropriate, after visiting the pages some files are created in the cache folder but the pages that we have visited are not created in the cache folder, Can anyone give a solution?